# Core plot : ios show two y axis and ScaterPlot and Bar Plot in Same CPTGraph

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-plot

Hi please guide me write way to show two Y axis (left side and right side) with one x axis using core plot , and also i have to draw Scaterplot and barplot both in single CPTGraph.
CPTScatter plot show on right side Y axis with -ve direction .

My Code snippet

```
-(void)configureAxes
{
    // 1 - Configure styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 8.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 8.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

    // 2 - Get the graph's axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;

    // 3 - Configure the x-axis
//    axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
//    axisSet.xAxis.title = @"";
//    axisSet.xAxis.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentRight;
//    axisSet.xAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
//    axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 38.0f;
//    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
//    axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    CGFloat dateCount = [self.arrayData count];
    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
    NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
    NSInteger i = 0;
    for (ResolutionData *d in self.arrayData)
    {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[[d.appName componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]objectAtIndex:0]  textStyle:axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle];
//        [label setRotation:45.0];
        CGFloat location = i++;
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
        label.offset = axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength;
        if (label) {
            [xLabels addObject:label];
            [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
        }
    }
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLabels = xLabels;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLocations = xLocations;


    // 4 - Configre the y-axis
    CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.title = @"count";
    y.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentCenter;
    y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.titleOffset = -40.0f;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y.labelOffset = 16.0f;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
//    y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
//    y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    NSInteger majorIncrement = 20;
    NSInteger minorIncrement = 10;
    CGFloat yMax = 100.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    int   x =1;
    for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
        NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
        if (mod == 0) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
            [label setAlignment:CPTAlignmentTop];
            NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);x++;
            label.tickLocation = location;
            label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
            if (label) {
                [yLabels addObject:label];
            }
            [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
        } else {
            [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
        }
    }

    y.axisLabels = yLabels;
    y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
    y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new y-axis object, configure it as desired, and add it to the axis set.

```
axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, y2, nil];
```

If you want a different scale for the right y-axis, you need another plot space. Create a new one, configure it, set the `xRange` to the same `xRange` as the default plot space, and add it to the graph. Make sure the new y-axis has its `plotSpace` set to the new plot space object.

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *oldPlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
CPTXYPlotSpace *newPlotSpace = [[[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init] autorelease];
newPlotSpace.xRange = oldPlotSpace.xRange;
newPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:/* location */
                                                   length:/* length */];
[graph addPlotSpace:linearPlotSpace];
```

See the "Axis Demo" and "Plot Space Demo" in the *Plot Gallery* example app for sample code.

Comment: :Thanks It works for me. but one problem i need to draw scatter plot according to right side y axis ...now it's draw from left y axis and taking right side y axis coordinate  how can i do it ?

Comment: Use the `-addPlot:toPlotSpace:` method instead of `-addPlot` to add the plot to the graph. Set the plot space to the one you created for the second y-axis.

Comment: I did same what you suggest but it's not working  [self.graph addPlot:actualPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace2];

Comment: For 2nd Y axis i am write bellow code switch (fieldEnum)
            {
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
                    if (index < valueCount) {
                        return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:  { //pd.actual-alotPoint


                        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:pd.actual];
               }
                    break;
            }
            return [NSDecimalNumber zero];

Comment: How can i share a screen shot..?

Comment: You need a certain amount of reputation to embed images in a question. Post it anywhere you want on the web and post a link instead.

Comment: You Can see the screenshot here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujvvu2nqsi7ldev/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-23%20at%2011.29.41%20AM.png

Comment: I want to draw the scatter plot from y2 axis ..now it's drawing from y1 ...:)

Comment: Did you add the scatter plot to the same plot space used by the y2 axis?